# How can I exclude HTML text nodes from the browser's search function?

Tags: html, browser, accessibility

Is there some ARIA or other way to mark a given HTML node so as to be skipped when the user searches for text on the page (Ctrl+F/Cmd+F)?

**Use case**: hiding accessible/fallback text from searches

**Example**: search on this page for the word `down`. You should only find the instance in the previous sentence, but Chrome will show as many search results as there are answers to this question, plus one, because the question itself, and each answer, have a "d... vote" `a` link text.

[image]

Such search results aren't highlighted, and it can appear frustrating to see "1 of X" in the search box, while there's nothing visible that matches what the user has searched for.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I understood you correctly, but if you develop your own app, not hacking SO source, maybe using of CSS `:before` or `:after` pseudo-elements filled with `content` property will help.

For example, the text ”Hello“ is not found in Safari, Chrome and Firefox when added by the `content` property:

```
.text:before {
    content: 'Hello';
}
```

Opera 12.x finds the word on the page, so if its support makes sense for you, this solution won't work. I also haven't test it in any version of IE, mobile browsers and other infrequent environments.

Answer (score 0):

In the example you could remove the "down vote" text (replacing it with `&nbsp;`, whitespace, or empty string) because the `a` tag already contains a `title` attributes which aimed to be used by screen readers.

The fallback is then only necessary with a text browser like lynx, which will ignore CSS. So, you can use a markup like

```
 <a href="#" title="Explicit alternative">
    <span class="hidden">Explicit alternative</span>
 </a>
```

Setting `display:none` on class `hidden`

If you doubt that your `title` attribute is enough, you could add an `aria-label` attribute, but it's not necessary.